# image url request on iOS since server moved, but android is fine

Tags: php, ios, linux, apache, google-cloud-platform

I have a shopping project use PHP+Apache2 on Ubuntu14 as server backend.
And iOS Android for frontend.

My server was running on local machine. Every thing was fine.
But since I move my server to Google Cloud Platform.
the image url request became very slow ***only on iOS***, android work as well as it can.

I have no idea, can anyone give me a hint what make this situation?

--
More info

Okay I'll try explain more detail. But it is hard to say it.

1. My GCP locate at Taiwan and my users all Taiwanese, I am running on GCP Compute Engine
2. No errors, no logs related.
3. Slow means in Android app it took less than 1 second to GET images. But iOS took more than 5 seconds.
4. [Here](https://api.jiehung.com.tw/5yuan-web/treasure/data/normal_production/1000165/s_pic.jpg?1598456346) is a link to my image api service

--

I found what exactly where the problem is, it is cause the decode of images cost a lot of time.
but i still not figure out how to fix it, any help?
[image]

Comment: can you explain more about this? just saying "slow" is not enough there could be thousands of reason for this. where does your server live in GCP? what is the expected latency? do you have any errors? please give more context so I can help you. any logs, screenshots, graphs would be very helpful

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi I added more info for u, plz check. thanks

Comment: I understand that your server api runs on Compute Engine. with your android app, everything works fine and you don't notice "slowness" and that happerns only with your ios app. How did you notice this slowness (yourself or your users reported it)? where does your images resides (are they in a bucket) ? can you post a code snippet from your ios app on how you are getting the images?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi I post my code of iOS App below :)

Comment: I would say add more logging to server code and app code and check where the latency is generated. From description it looks like your image download code is not optimal. I can't help with it, try searching and utilizing other methods/libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];
    
    NSString *sessionToken = [_defaults stringForKey:Member_Session_token];
    NSLog(@"sessionToken: %@", sessionToken);
    
    if (sessionToken.length != 0) {
        [request setValue:sessionToken forHTTPHeaderField:Header];
    }
    
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
```

Here is the code to access image.

My images is stored with my server, not in bucket.